# Creating database with oracle dbca

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

Using DBCA tool, a backup of a database template is made from a ORacle 11.2.0.3.

Using this template files, creating a new database on the same machine or differenct machine with same version of ORACLE 11.2.0.3 is fine.

The fun part comes when using to create database with DBCA on different version of oracle say 11.2.0.4.

This is the error set i get:

> DBCA_PROGRESS : 5% Copying database files DBCA_PROGRESS : 7%
>   DBCA_PROGRESS : 9% DBCA_PROGRESS : 16% DBCA_PROGRESS : 23%
>   DBCA_PROGRESS : 30% DBCA_PROGRESS : 37% DBCA_PROGRESS : 41% Creating
>   and starting Oracle instance DBCA_PROGRESS : 43% DBCA_PROGRESS : 44%
>   ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced ORA-00704:
>   bootstrap process failure ORA-39700: database must be opened with
>   UPGRADE option
>
> ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced ORA-00704:
>   bootstrap process failure ORA-39700: database must be opened with
>   UPGRADE option
>
> DBCA_PROGRESS : 100%

It would be helpful if anyone could point if DBCA does not support this or workaround is there

Comment: did you investigate this line: ORA-39700: database must be opened with UPGRADE option ?

Comment: I didn`t get what you meant. The template is using the upgraded version, so its throwing the error. Thats the question. How do i overcome it.

Comment: http://www.dbaglobe.com/2009/08/ora-00704-bootstrap-process-failure.html

Comment: That`s using the default the template. Mine is backup database template from previous version. However tried that and it fails still.